# Tabs Widget Difficulty - New Tab Div Text Shows in All Tabs

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, tabs

I just learned of the Tabs Widget, and made a quick block of code which adds a tab when the button "add tab" is clicked and removes a tab when the "remove tab" button is clicked. I used the book "Projquery" as a reference. Unfortunately, whenever the button "add tab" is clicked instead of adding only one tab with content, it also adds the new tab's content to all the preceding tabs as well. I've checked the syntax 12 times over, but to no avail. An answer would definitely be appreciated :)

The Issue - Button Adds new tab with content, as well as div text to old tabs, which it shouldn't

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
   $("#tabs").tabs();

   $("button").button().click(function(e){
    var tabsElem = $("#tabs");
    if(this.id == "add"){
       var tabID = tabsElem.children("div").length + 1;
       tabsElem.children("ul").append($("<li>").append($("<a>")
        .attr("href","#Tab " + tabID).text("Tab " + tabID)));
        $("<div>").attr("id","Tab" + tabID).text("Cotent for given tab number " 
            + tabID +", and BAM").appendTo(tabsElem);
    }else{
        tabsElem.children("div").first().remove();
        tabsElem.find("li").first().remove();
    }
    tabsElem.tabs("refresh");

   });
})
</script>
<body>
<div id = "tabs">
  <ul>
     <li><a href="#Tab1">Tab 1</a></li>
     <li><a href="#Tab2">Tab 2</a></li>
     <li><a href="#Tab3">Tab 3</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div id ="Tab1">Mad Content Don'tcha Y'know</div>
  <div id = "Tab2">Welcome to the free world, you hear</div>
  <div id = "Tab3">Last Time For Now</div>
</div>
<br />
<div id = "button" class = "ui-widget">
  <button id = "add">Add Tab!!!</button>
  <button id = "remove">Remove Tab!!!</button>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Note - For brevity's sake I left out the head tag with the jquery/css links

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you needed to check the syntax a baker's dozen times ;)

The issue is your setting of the anchor href attribute:

```
.attr("href","#Tab " + tabID)
```

Note the space between "#Tab" and the 'tabID' you concatenate with it; that results in href attributes of "Tab 4", "Tab 5", etc. The problem with that is your newly created DIVs do not have said space (and good thing too - a space isn't a valid char in an ID per the [HTML spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/types.html#type-id)):

```
$("<div>").attr("id","Tab" + tabID)
```

I confirmed that fixing the setting of the "href" on the appended anchor addresses the issue here: http://jsfiddle.net/2bxJ6/1/

Comment: Awesome thank you :) it fixes the problem, but after removing a tab and then adding one everything goes to hell again, the same problem occurs

Comment: The result you're seeing when removing, then adding a Tab is simply a function of this line "var tabID = tabsElem.children('div').length + 1;". This is because you're using the count of existing tabs, plus one, to determine the ID of the new tab - but if there is already a tab with that ID, you now have a dupe, resulting in the odd behavior. Consider this updated jsFiddle that uses a custom .data() property on the #tabs element to ensure an ID is never repeated: http://jsfiddle.net/2bxJ6/5/

Comment: Yeah I realized this a little after posting, thanks for the explanation, the updated code, and the answer, you've been a great help :)